# When are qt windows created?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, window-management

If QWidget is created without a parent, it creates a window.

So, when exactly is the window created? Is it when the `show()` is called? Or when the object is constructed?

Answer (score 1):

Window is created when the `show()` method is called. If you set widget's parent before showing a widget, no window is created.

Comment: That was my understanding as well, but do you have a link that explains that? Accessing window's id before calling show works fine.

Comment: As QWidget::winId documentation says, "If a widget is non-native (alien) and winId() is invoked on it, that widget will be provided a native handle." I think window id for invisible widget is created when you call winId().

Comment: But it is not possible to get window's Id, without creating a window first. It can happen that a window is created in the constructor (using XCreateWindow), and then that it is shown when show() is called using XMapWindow.